# Can I access old (EdgeHTML) Edge after installing Chrome-based Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Windows 10 comes with EdgeHTML-based Edge. After installing the new Chrome-based Edge, the old Edge seems to be gone, but I doubt that Microsoft would actually remove the old Edge from the system. My guess is that they hide it somewhere and just made it not visible to the user. So, is there any way to access it? I mean, without uninstalling the Chrome-based Edge.

Comment: Have you installed the required Edge for Business Policy Definitions?

Comment: I am back in my home office and am posting this within Legacy Edge and I have Chromium Edge running another website. I have had this setup for over a year now. I did some reading and it is possible (even likely) that if you are just starting out with this you may indeed have to add a registry key (or a policy) to make it work. Just another example of more than one way to do things. Both browsers are easily selectable.

Answer (score 1):

Edge and Chromium-base Edge have two different icons.

You can very easily select Edge  or select Chromium. They both work and do not conflict. I installed Chromium nearly a year ago and this is how it works for me.

New **information:  If** you are starting now, you might wish to add two registry keys (picky, I know): EdgeUpdate and Allowsxs  (value 1), before installing Chromium. After setting the keys, install Chromium and it will work.   See this article.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/tutorial-how-to-run-legacy-and-chromium-based-edge/m-p/1121216

Either because you might have installed it or because you are now doing it, Edge and Edge Chromium work side by side.
Edge updates via Windows Updates. Chromium Edge is an App that updates via App updates. Both will update properly.

There is no harm at all to installing and using Chromium Edge.

Comment: Microsoft recommends you set the value of AllowSxS before you install Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Nice point and I added it. I neglected to to so the first time

Answer (score -1):

No. the old edge is gone. The new one replaces everything of the old edge. I hope you got your answer.

Comment: This answer isn’t correct.  It absolutely is possible to still launch Legacy Edge provided the system is configured properly.